# How to change alignment of a div item on a mobile website?

Tags: html, css

I have this block that calculates the total and I was wondering how I could fix the overflow problem on a mobile version (attachment #1). I am trying to move it to the left side (or at least that it would not go beyond the screen) but I have no clue how to do that.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
.ezfc-fixed {
    background: #fff0;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image: Mobile preview]

[image: Desktop preview]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving it left or right properties

```
right: 20px;
```

This would position it 20px right from the body, so even if you scale down it remains at the same position

for responsive

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
.ezfc-fixed {
  background: #fff0;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  min-width: max-content;
 }}
```

If I'm correct, that's bootstrap sm's breakpoint

Comment: But how do I set it to be only on a mobile? What property should I use?

Comment: use css media queries @media screen and (max-width: 576px)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I just have no idead what I am doing wrong. Could you take a look at the website? I've tried to use .ezfc-fixed instead of .header, but to no avail :( 
https://aversrh.ru/services/

Comment: I'm editing the code again, the issues is with your width that's why it overflows... great website by the way. you can use min-width or width, but i recommend min-width so it can break if needed. This should work

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make responsive, you should use @media - css query in that case. And If you wanna move, then position relative for parent, position absolute for child and after that use "right" to move. I hope It will help you